# If $f_n \in L^1$, will the limit function $f$ also be in $L^1$ in monotone convergence theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, limits, integration

[Monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem) doesn't require the sequence of functions $f_n$'s to be $L^1$. When $f_n\in L^1$, will its pointwise limit function $f$ also be in $L^1$? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Define $f_n$ as follows.

On $[-n,n]$, set $f_n(x):=1$ and $f_n(x):=0$ elsewhere.

Each $f_n$ is in $L^1$.

But the pointwise limit, which is equal to the constant function $f(x)=1$ on $\mathbb{R}$, is not in $L^1$.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite, since the monotone convergence theorem includes the case where $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n \ d\mu = \infty$.  But if the limit is finite, $f \in L^1$.

Comment: Thank you! Why is $\lim_{n→∞}∫f_n dμ=∞$, if $f_n \in L^1$?

Comment: Why not?  @julien provided one example, it's easy to find many others.